# Get values from xml variable in a single column

Tags: xml, t-sql

Try to get values from xml variable in single column from CCC tag, num attribute.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '
<FileId global_id="1234">
  <file id="12bb"><vd>3</vd>
    <pl_b type_b ="222" k="222" name="bbb"></pl_b>
    <period from="2019-04-01" to="2019-06-30"></period>
    <all>2</all>
    <CCC num = "123" />
    <CCC num = "444" />
  </file>
</FileId>'
```

```
Expected Result:
|num|
|---|
|123|
|444|
```

Now I can get only one value:

```
SELECT
    F.[File].value(N'(CCC/@num)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as acc
FROM (VALUES (@XML)) V (X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/FileId/file') F([File]);
```

The problem is it's unknown how many values can be get from xml. In example 2 values also may be 2 two thousand.
Second question is how can extract how many values in CCC tag, num attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much more performant way without `CROSS APPLY`. I put *Query cost* in the comments for comparison.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<FileId global_id="1234">
  <file id="12bb"><vd>3</vd>
    <pl_b type_b ="222" k="222" name="bbb"></pl_b>
    <period from="2019-04-01" to="2019-06-30"></period>
    <all>2</all>
    <CCC num = "123" />
    <CCC num = "444" />
  </file>
</FileId>';

-- Method #1
-- Query cost 97%
SELECT F.CCC.value(N'(@num)[1]', 'int') AS acc --I assume int is actually the correct datatype
FROM (VALUES (@XML)) V (X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/FileId/file/CCC') F([CCC]);

-- Method #2
-- Query cost 3%
SELECT c.value('.', 'INT') AS num
FROM @xml.nodes('/FileId/file/CCC/@num') t(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

*"Now I can get only one value:"* because you're only asking for the first value **`(CCC/@num)[1]`**. This means the first node for `CCC/@Num`, which would be `123`.

You need to include the `CCC` node in your `CROSS APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT F.CCC.value(N'(@num)[1]', 'int') AS acc --I assume int is actually the correct datatype
FROM (VALUES (@XML)) V (X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/FileId/file/CCC') F([CCC]);
```